# How do I limit messages per day for an user?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know this is a opinion based question, but I need your opinions.

In my app I want to limit messages a user can send each day. At first I thought I would store the date of first message sent by user and limit his/her for that day.

But what about the time difference between user location and my server location. So if my user is 5 hours ahead of server, user won't be able to send any messages until server timezone reaches next day which is a 5 hours lag from users perspective.

And if I take users timezone from their mobiles, they can change their timezone and easily break the limit.

So how do I tackle this problem? I'm using Laravel, MySQL.

Comment: Not really an opinion, but it is rather open. What you may need to do is figure out someone's timezone (maybe through javascript or a user setting) so you can adjust the time you are doing the math with. Or you can just see what's been posted in the past 24 hours. No, that's not by day, but closest to until you find the right solution... ;)

Comment: limiting by past 24 hours would have been easy. Its the date thing that's bugging me

Comment: You really only read the last few words of my reply? You were only asking in theory (or hypothetically). The technique is not dependent on the framework you use nor the database. Like I said, you need to figure out the timezone of the user, figure out what would've been the start of his/her day and add a second parameter that is the start + 24 hours...

Comment: No I read your full comment. :) I thought about it. But if you consume your  limit for a day and then change your timezone then you get to message more right?

Comment: Not everything is bulletproof... How many people do you know would try and change their timezone? ;) Sometimes you may have to accept the few that defy the system...

Comment: But once someone figures it out, I can only hope for that he won't tell anyone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130668/discussion-between-raphioly-san-and-sayantan-das).

Comment: if 'changing time zones' is genuinely a concern, then you just have to restrict messages according to either 1. the site's time zone, perhaps with a disclaimer on the site which explains that, or 2. The time zone of the user's first message of that (circa) *48* hour period

Comment: @Strawberry I was thinking about your last suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just count last day messages using Carbon's `subDays()` or `subHours()`:

```
$numberOfMessages = Message::where('user_id', 1)
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->count();
if ($numberOfMessages >= $dailyLimit) {
    return;
}
```

This will work for you if you just want to limit number of messages for last 24 hours. If you care about **calendar day** of each user (when each one has different timezone), this won't work.

Comment: Tracking last 24 hours is easy. I have to reset the limit at 12.00 AM every day, for each user, from different timezones :(

Comment: You could also allow the user to set their timezone and use Carbon's timezone method to alter the server time to reflect the users time.